# How to speed up Frangi filtering in opencv (c++)

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I have this image:

[image]

I want to detect anomalies on this image by using Frangi filter. Code for it i got here: [Frangi filter](https://github.com/ntnu-bioopt/libfrangi/blob/master/README.md). I use this parameters for frangi filter:

```
  // Manualy edited parameters of frangi filter.
#define DEFAULT_SIGMA_START 1
#define DEFAULT_SIGMA_END 3
#define DEFAULT_SIGMA_STEP 1
#define DEFAULT_BETA_ONE 1.6
#define DEFAULT_BETA_TWO 1.2
#define DEFAULT_BLACKWHITE true
```

Anomaly detection works very ok. The problem is speed of calculation. The time for filtering is: 7 seconds. What can be possible solutions for speeding up while mainaining good detection with Frangi Filter?

EDIT 1: The code where the most time is spend is for loop inside of a frangi2d algorithm:

```
for (float sigma = opts.sigma_start; sigma <= opts.sigma_end; sigma += opts.sigma_step) {
        //create 2D hessians
        Mat Dxx, Dyy, Dxy;
        frangi2d_hessian(src, Dxx, Dxy, Dyy, sigma);

        //correct for scale
        Dxx = Dxx*sigma*sigma;
        Dyy = Dyy*sigma*sigma;
        Dxy = Dxy*sigma*sigma;

        //calculate (abs sorted) eigenvalues and vectors
        Mat lambda1, lambda2, Ix, Iy;
        frangi2_eig2image(Dxx, Dxy, Dyy, lambda1, lambda2, Ix, Iy);

        //compute direction of the minor eigenvector
        Mat angles;
        phase(Ix, Iy, angles);
        ALLangles.push_back(angles);

        //compute some similarity measures
        lambda2.setTo(nextafterf(0, 1), lambda2 == 0);
        Mat Rb = lambda1.mul(1.0 / lambda2);
        Rb = Rb.mul(Rb);
        Mat S2 = lambda1.mul(lambda1) + lambda2.mul(lambda2);

        //compute output image
        Mat tmp1, tmp2;
        exp(-Rb / beta, tmp1);
        exp(-S2 / c, tmp2);

        Mat Ifiltered = tmp1.mul(Mat::ones(src.rows, src.cols, src.type()) - tmp2);
        if (opts.BlackWhite) {
            Ifiltered.setTo(0, lambda2 < 0);
        }
        else {
            Ifiltered.setTo(0, lambda2 > 0);
        }

        //store results
        ALLfiltered.push_back(Ifiltered);

        cout << "Interation done" << endl;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your image has a big black region, you can select a ROI it, in order to apply the filter.

The ROI selection may be based on pre proccesig the images looking for the vertex of the ROI. Maybe it is fixed for your application. Maybe you can use other info to select the ROI.

```
Rect region_of_interest = Rect(x, y, w, h);
Mat image_roi = image(region_of_interest);
```

Comment: Thats a good point, but I already tried and still doesn't bring me a lot more of a speed. I have to go inside of a frangi filtering algorithm and optimize it.

Comment: I also added a code where most time is spend in frangi2d funtion (for loop)